# Fastlane match setup, using match appstore and match development

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

I am trying to setup fastlane match but am having trouble understanding this step:

After running fastlane `match init` you can run the following to generate new certificates and profiles:

```
fastlane match appstore
fastlane match development
```

What exactly is `appstore` and `development`? Are they supposed be assumed scheme names? My app has two schemes (both have different bundle identifiers) they are called `MyApp` and `MyApp UAT` do I need to run `fastlane match MyApp` and `fastlane match MyApp UAT`?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not schemes, they are cert/prov of some types.

Yes, you need to create the cert of any kind for each BundId.
Each certificate represent a BundleID and each prov. profile is dependent of a certificate so... yes, you need to create each cert, and then each prov. profile, as you will do manually on iTC.

Run `fastlane match --help` and it clarify your question

> ```
> adhoc               Run match for a adhoc provisioning profile
> appstore            Run match for a appstore provisioning profile
> change_password     Re-encrypt all files with a different password
> decrypt             Decrypts the repository and keeps it on the filesystem
> development         Run match for a development provisioning profile
> enterprise          Run match for a enterprise provisioning profile
> [...]
> ```

You see, development mean which is not distribution, you could create also adhoc, etc.. and appStore mean distribution for not the enterprise bundleID.

Any doubt, please ask me ;)

Comment: Hello, can you please take a look at my question? Maybe you can help solve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331096/adhoc-and-appstore-builds-with-fastlane-match

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm happy you already found the solution, and sorry but anyway I have not used Fastlen for long time so I could not help you anyway.