# AdHoc and Appstore builds with Fastlane match

Tags: ios, firebase, circleci, fastlane, fastlane-match

I want to be able to do both `adhoc` builds for `Firebase Distribution` and `appstore` builds for TestFlight/AppStore. I'm also using CI/CD system (`CircleCI`). I use `Fastlane match` for builds signing. My question is how to do switch between different type of certificates when do different type of builds?

My idea was to set up in Xcode for Debug configuration adhoc signing certificate, and for release configuration appstore certificate. However, when I tested this approach, turns out that adhoc builds are crashing immediately after the app launch, so it looks like this approach is not correct.

[image]

Here is my Fastfile:

```
platform :ios do
  before_all do
    setup_circle_ci
  end

  desc "Runs tests and build the app "
  lane :testandbuild do |options|
     commit = last_git_commit
     # Uncomment the line if you want to increment build number  
     # increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "MyApp.xcodeproj")
     scan(
        scheme: "MyApp"
    )
    if(options[:branch] == "main")
      increment_build_number
      keyFilePath = File.join(Dir.pwd, "appStoreKey.p8")
      app_store_connect_api_key(
        key_id: options[:key_id],
        issuer_id: options[:issuer_id],
        key_filepath: keyFilePath,
        # duration: 1200,
        in_house: false,
      )
      match(type: "appstore", readonly: "false")
      build_app(
          scheme: "MyApp",
        configuration: "Release"
      )
      upload_to_testflight(
        skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
      )
    else
       match(type: "adhoc")
       gym(export_method: "ad-hoc", scheme: "MyApp", configuration: "Debug" , output_directory: "../output")
       firebase_app_distribution(
               groups: 'dev-team',
               release_notes: "Branch: #{options[:branch]}. Message: #{commit[:message]}",
               firebase_cli_token: options[:firebase_cli_token]
       )
    end       
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution inside the `gym` I added
`xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='match AdHoc myapp.com'"` for `adhoc` build and for `appStore` build I added `xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='match AppStore myapp.com'"`.

I removed for AdHoc build `configuration: "Debug"`.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like the following in my gym.

```
gym(
    workspace: xcodeworkspace,
    scheme: environment,
    configuration: environment,
    silent: true,
    clean: true,
    export_method: "ad-hoc",
    export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: { 
            app_identifier => app_profile_name,
            balance_widget_identifier => balance_widget_profile_name
        }
    }
)
```

This way I can define a different profile (for different builds) for the "today extension" as well.